# Angular filter posts using pipes

Tags: html, angular, pipe, ngfor

I'm trying to filter posts of a table in Angular using pipes, but I keep getting on the console this error: core.js:12689 Can't bind to 'ngForFilter' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.

I think the error is on filter: filterPost, but dont know how to fix it. Any clue?

My html code is the following.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Busca un reporte</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="filterPost" placeholder="Busca.." [(ngModel)]="filterPost">
  </div>
<a *ngFor="let report of All_reports | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: actualPage }; let i = index; 
filter: filterPost" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start" [routerLink]="['/reporte-admin']" 
routerLinkActive="router-link-active" (click)="onSubmit(report._id)">

    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
        <h5 class="mb-1">Reporte #: {{report._id}}</h5>
        <small>{{i+1}}</small>
    </div>
      <p class="mb-1">Comentario: {{report.comentario}}</p>
      <small class="text-muted">Nombre: {{report.nombre}} {{report.apellido}}</small>
</a>
<br>
```

This is my filter.pipe.ts code:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, arg: any): any {
    const resultPosts = [];
    for(const report of value){
      if(report._id.indexOf(arg) > -1){
        resultPosts.push(report);
      };
    };
    return resultPosts;
  }

}
```

Comment: Whats the name of the pipe you gave in @Pipe decorator?

Comment: @Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe operator "`|`" expects some value to the left of it.
In your case, you added the pipe operator at the end after `let i=index;`

I believe you should do something like this

```
*ngFor="let report of All_reports | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: actualPage } | filter: filterPost; let i = index;"
```

and also dont forget to add in `declarations` in app module

Comment: Thank you, @Supercool.! I was stuck for a while, it worked without any problem.

Comment: I closed my computer and opened again and know its not working, look, this error is appearing: core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at FilterPipe.transform (filter.pipe.ts:11)
    at pureFunction2Internal (core.js:36845)
    at Module.ɵɵpipeBind2 (core.js:37027)
    at AllReportsComponent_Template (all-reports.component.html:5)

Comment: Its the logic inside your transform that is giving error. Particularly inside that for loop